# How can i check a function result after multi seconds in node.js?

Tags: node.js

i am intercepting page request i want to wait for special request for 20 second and after that chek response? if i use setTimeout 0r set interval, request send after 20 second but i want on page load request send and code after that wait for the response for 20 second
this is robot code and speed isnot  matter for it

```
   page.on('response',async (response)=>{
     if(response.url().endWith('whatever'){
           x=response.status===200
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
page.on('response',async (response)=>{

     await sleep(20000);

     if(response.url().endWith('whatever')){
           x=response.status===200
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i use promises in my case i wait a promise that inside it intercept request and anyway resolve after 20 see my code in the following

```
 let response_received=await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                   page.on('response',async (response)=>{
                       if (response.url().endsWith('quickDailySalesReport')){
                           console.log(response);
                          if ( response.status()===200){
                                await sleep(2000);
                                resolve(true)
                          }
                       }
                     });
                    setTimeout(()=>resolve(false),20000)
               });
                console.log(response_received);
               if (response_received){//do something}
```